# ldap loop through OU and get users c#

Tags: c#, ldap

I have an AD on the Server. 
For Example this is my Strukture

-- A

-> Peter

--- B

---- > Sabrina

---- BA

------> John

---- BAA

--------> Frank

---- BB

------> Michael

-- C

I want to loop through this groups starting with B and get only Users.
In this exaple i should have the following Users John, Frank, Michael, Sabrina.
Can i get it with a Filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution:
First i get a list of all OU and nested OU.
Then i loop through my List an find seatch for my users.

```
        List<string> orgUnits = new List<string>();
        DirectoryEntry startingPoint = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=STARTINGOU,DC=intranet,DC=pspiess,DC=local");
        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(startingPoint);
        searcher.Filter = "(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)";
        foreach (SearchResult res in searcher.FindAll()) {
            orgUnits.Add(res.Path);
        }
        orgUnits.ForEach(delegate(String orgUnit) {
            var entry = new DirectoryEntry(orgUnit);
            var aDs = new DirectorySearcher(entry) { Filter = "(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=user))" };

            foreach (SearchResult aSr in aDs.FindAll()) {
                //Some Code
            }
        });
```